# ManyToMany with same tables in entity - Symfony, Doctrine

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have two ManyToMany relations in one entity.

**First**:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="RFQItem")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="rfqitem_to_rfq",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="rfqitem", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $rfqitems;
```

**Second**:

```
 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="RFQItem", cascade={"persist"})
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="new_rfqitem_to_rfq",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="rfqitem", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 * )
 */
protected $rfq_item;
```

Problem is that I can't generate my entities and update schema, because generating entities gives me dublicated methods:

```
/**
 * Add rfq_item
 *
 * @param \RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\RFQItem $rfqItem
 * @return RFQ
 */
public function addRfqItem(\RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\RFQItem $rfqItem)
{
    $this->rfq_item[] = $rfqItem;

    return $this;
}
```

which throws an error:

```
Fatal error: Cannot redeclare RFQ\IronilBundle\Entity\RFQ::addRfqitem()
```

I need these two relations in one entity, because one is for adding previously made RFQitems, but second is to create new RFQitems and this all is in one form.
What I can do resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doctrine generate methods with names based on your fields. Your fields are very similar: Doctrine will omit ending "s" and underscores, convert strings to lowercase. Your fields will look like `$rfqitem` and `$rfqitem`. As you can see Doctrine will see your fields with two absolutely equal names. You need to rename one of your fields `$rfqitems`, `$rfq_item`.

Try something more semantic like: `$oldRFQItems` and `$newRFQItems`.